# my PC is unable to connect to my phone hotspot

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

when i try and connect to my mobile hotspot i put in the password and i get a 'can't connect to this network' message.

I'm in NYC and able to connect to the optimumwifi access points around the city but im unable to connect to my hotspot

a day or two ago i updated my pc and i think it was a reasonably big update (it updated bios etc.) and ii didn't notice any change until i tried to connect to my hotspot because my other WIFI went out.

i did change my wireless card about 3 months ago from the HP AW-NB274NF that came with the laptop and it was working fine.

what I've tried: i uninstalled and installed my drivers a few times. change the to max the 2.4 ghz antenna to 20ghz instead of auto and it didn't let me connect to anything so i changed back. disabling ipv6. delete some files from the registry editor(dont remember exacly which ones but i follow instructions i found online). tried pretty much everything on the first page of google when i searched this message .

honestly forgot everything i tried

Device: HP- 7FQ26AV

Network Card: Intel WIFI 6 AX200NGW.

EDIT: ran windows update a bit ago and i don't know what happened but started working

Comment: What's the OS version of your windows? Try restarting your mobile as well as your Windows laptop. Once both the devices reboot, try connecting with the hotspot again. Also run Network troubleshooter, see if it can detect any error message.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I restarted everything multiple times and changed the SSID and password of the hotspot.  The troubleshooter just adds networks to automatically connect to and when I'm connected to the public hotspot it tells me it doesn't like the DNS but otherwise nothing